# Detect key status in zsh from the Linux console

Tags: linux, scripting, keyboard, console

Can zsh detect a key status without a tool that depends on a graphical session?

I've overwritten the getty@tty1 service to autologin, and `zlogin` executes sway. I would like to prevent running a graphical interface when the shift key is held down by unsetting `rcs`. Is there Something similar to grub's [keystatus](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/keystatus.html)?

Comment: Zsh itself can't because terminals don't transmit this information. You need to call a tool that depends on the terminal. Which OS are you running?

Comment: Why would you unset `rcs`? Why not `if ! shift_key_is_pressed; then startx; fi` in `.zlogin` or `.zprofile`?

Comment: `4.19.2-arch1-1-ARCH #1 x86_64 GNU/Linux`. You're right about the if statement: .zlogin is the last startup file anyways. I just like to think of it as an "abort sequence".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminals don't transmit this information. You need to call an external utility (or write a zsh loadable module) that is specific to the Linux console. It would need to call one of the [Linux console ioctl](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_ioctl.4.html), specifically `TIOCLINUX` to obtain the shift state. Keyboard-related utilities are in the [`kbd` package](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=kbd), but I don't think there is one that reports modifier states.

You can find the code for such a utility at [a similar question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13657889/check-if-the-shift-key-is-currently-being-held-in-the-linux-text-fb-console).

If you don't want to rely on an additional utility, the kbd package includes [`kbdinfo`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/kbdinfo.1.html) which can report the LED state.

```
# Start X if Caps Lock is on
if kbdinfo gkbled capslock; then
  setleds -D -caps
  exec startx
fi
```

Comment: The c program on the linked question works great. It's weird that I missed that. thanks